# show same slideshow on different sites

Tags: features, views

how to show the same slideshow view on different sites but with different images - I have multiple sites which needs to show the same slideshow with different images. Can anyone explain how to go about this. I am relatively new to drupal and I have already setup the slidehow view / cycle module and created slideshow view and slideshow content type for one of the site and its working al good. Now I want to replicate the same on the other site (all the themes and the templates and css are the same its basically white labelling) but just use different images.

Answer (score 2):

You should try the [features](http://drupal.org/project/features) module

> The features module enables the capture and management of features in
>   Drupal. A feature is a collection of Drupal entities which taken
>   together satisfy a certain use-case.
>
> Features provides a UI and API for taking different site building
>   components from modules with exportables and bundling them together in
>   a single feature module. A feature module is like any other Drupal
>   module except that it declares its components (e.g. views, contexts,
>   CCK fields, etc.) in its .info file so that it can be checked,
>   updated, or reverted programmatically.
>
> Examples of features might be:
>
> - A blog
> - A pressroom
> - An image gallery
> - An e-commerce t-shirt store

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the Features module recommendation, but if Features is too complicated or you don't have access to Drush, you can do the following.

1. Install the modules on the second site.
2. Make sure all the content types you use in the slideshow have the same names on both sites.
3. Export the view on the site with the slideshow.  You can do this by going to the page that lists all your views, clicking the little triangle next to the view, and choosing "export view."  Copy this code.
4. On the site that doesn't have the view yet, go to the views listing page and choose "import view."  Paste the code you copied in #3.

Features will automate all of this into a single step, but if this is something you're only going to do once or need to do right away, the above approach may be faster.

Comment: +1, but I think the last paragraph could use some clarification. The big drawback of this approach is when you want to do updates, you need to redo all the steps for every single minor update. Also, I'm not sure how gracefully this will handle "replacing" Views, will you need to delete them first?

Comment: If you need to update the view, just import it again.  On the import view screen, there is a checkbox to overwrite the view if it already exists.  Make sure to check that box!